# Routing in Svelte ? (Navigate between pages)

Tags: svelte

I am new to svelte. I want to know is there any inbuilt functionality to navigate between pages in svelte or do I have to use a third-party library like (As react-router for react.js)?

Answer (score 4):

There is no built in router for Svelte.
But there are several other options.

For single-page-applications, there are svelte-router, tinro, and others.
For multi page, the three big ones currently are Routify, ElderJS and SvelteKit.

Routify brings you routing and some other stuff (haven't used it often myself)

ElderJS is excellent for making very large static sites (1000+ pages)

SvelteKit is made by the Svelte team itself and is worth looking at if you want server side rendering, it is comparable to NextJS for React.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-routing

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinro

https://www.routify.dev/

https://github.com/Elderjs/elderjs

https://kit.svelte.dev/

Comment: Well, svelte-router now recommends using SvelteKit instead. Tinro appears to have been abandoned for about a year. And I sort of actively hate SvelteKit but that's not really relevant to this post. +1 for Routify though thx! Although it's another router that uses stupid filenames that always have to be escaped...what is WITH people? :o

Answer (score 1):

goto function
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation

Passing in your route to the goto('route') function should work.

```js
<script>
  import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

  function navigate() {
    goto('/another-route');
  }
</script>

<main>
  <button on:click={navigate}>
    Go to Another Route
  </button>
</main>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).